# Parse tags in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, parsing

I have created object like that

```
export const homeObjOne ={
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: true,
    lightTextDesc: true,
    topLine:'Explore DrukBox', // - working correctly
    headLine: 'Unlimited printing <br> with us',
    description: 'Lets <br> begin!', // - output: Lets <br> begin!(with br)
    buttonLabel: 'Get Started',
    imgStart: '',
    img: './assets/svg-1.svg',
    alt: 'DrukBox'
}
```

and bringing it to component like that

```
function HeroSection({
    lightBg,topLine,lightText,lightTextDesc,headLine,description,buttonLabel,img, alt, imgStart
}) {
    return (
        <div className={lightBg ? 'home__hero-section' : 'home__hero-section darkBg'}>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row home__hero-row"
                style={{display:'flex',flexDirection: imgStart === 'start' ? 'row-reverse' : 'row'}}
                >
```

*And so on*

```
                    <div className="home__hero-img-wrapper">
                        <img src={img} alt={alt}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but in the object my html code not parses i tried all types ',",`

```
import {homeObjOne} from './Data'
function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <HeroSection {...homeObjOne} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

- thats how i import object

Comment: Can you show us more of the component, specifically how you are importing `addPagesObjOne` and how you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

<del>You have created `addPagesObjOne` as a [JS Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).</del>

<del>To access the properties within this object and assuming `addPagesObjOne` has been:</del>

- <del>Imported into the component with your JSX or</del>
- <del>Within the component file</del>

<del>Then to correctly reference a property see this example:</del>

```
<img src={img} alt={alt}/>
```

<del>will become</del>

```
<img src={addPagesObjOne.img} alt={addPagesObjOne.alt}/>
```

**Update:**

I can see that you have provided an update to how you have laid out your code, [I created a quick sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-gossb) your code works fine. Maybe your assest is not in the correct place?

Comment: That is not an answer i have created component to universal usage, i cant change it for this

Comment: No,all code works correctly,there is the one that i cant insert html code to my props

Comment: You might need to update your question reflect the issue you are trying to solve, as it isn't clear what exactly is broken. :-)